# Cardinality of chain

Tags: abstract-algebra

$M$ is $n$-dimensional topological manifold.

Let $$\Delta^k = \{ (x_0,\ \cdots,\ x_k) |\ x_i\in {\bf R},\ \sum_{i=1}^k x_i = 1,\ x_i\geq 0 \ \},\ k\leq n$$

Let $C_k =\{ \sigma : \Delta^k\rightarrow M |\ \sigma$ is continuous $\}$

($C_k$ is a free $R$-module where $R$ is pid)

What is cardinal of $C_k$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinal number of $C_k$ in $\mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of real numbers, as every continuous function $\sigma:\Delta\to M$ is fully defined, once defined in countable a dense subset $D$ of $\Delta^k$. Hence, they are at most as many the functions $f:D\to M$. But these are:
$$
|M^D|=|(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}|=|2^{\aleph_0}|=\mathfrak{c}.
$$
At the same time there exist $\mathfrak{c}$ constant functions.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.